# Как зафиксировать фон на HTML???

Tags: html

<BODY BGCOLOR=silver text=black leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0 
background="pic/fon1.jpg" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">
<CENTER>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body style="background-color:silver; color:black; margin:0; background-image:url(pic/fon1.jpg); background-attachment:fixed; text-align: center;">
```

P.S. А еще лучше так:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color:silver; 
        color:black; 
        margin:0; 
        background-image:url(pic/fon1.jpg); 
        background-attachment:fixed; 
        text-align: center;
      }
      a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
        color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
```

Comment: Дело в том что я пишу на блакноте!

Comment: А) в блокноте все равно проще писать как я показал. Особенно, второй вариант.
Б) есть куча бесплатных редакторов, которые поддерживают подсветку синтаксиса. Хоть бы даже встроенный редактор Far"а или notepad++.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=win-1251">
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=silver text=black 
leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0 
background="pic/fon1.jpg" bgproperties="fixed" 
link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">
<CENTER>
<TABLE WIDTH=900 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=2>

Comment: и спасибо за помощь, я уже решил проблему